# Private member for singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton, initialization, member, default-constructor

I have a singleton class for which I need a private member. I want that member to be empty until I use my setter method to set the right data.

```
class PlaybackHelper{
private:
    PlaybackHelper();
    PlaybackHelper(PlaybackHelper const&);
    void operator=(PlaybackHelper const&);

    playback_type type;

    Note note;
public:
    void setPlaybackType(playback_type aType);
    static PlaybackHelper &getInstance();

};
```

Xcode is giving me an error in my implementation file (where I'm implementing my private constructor) saying that I should initialize my member:

```
PlaybackHelper::PlaybackHelper(){

}
```

`error: Semantic Issue: Constructor for 'PlaybackHelper' must explicitly initialize the member 'note' which does not have a default constructor`

I don't understand why I'm not able to do this (especially since it's not giving me any errors for the `playback_type type;` (enum) member which works the same way) Any ideas what I could do to leave my Note member empty until I'm ready to assign a value to it?

Comment: Object of type Node doesn't have default constructor, it's obviously after reading error text. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`playback_type` is a plain old data, thus lacking of initializing `type` simply leaves it as uninitialized; However, `class Note`'s non-default constructor is defined, and thus its default constructor would not be generated automatically if you did not define it.
To solve it, you could either

1. initialize it with the parameters of (one of the) non-default constructors defined by you.

   `PlaybackHelper::PlaybackHelper() : note(/*...*/)
   {
   }`
2. Define a default constructor for `class Note`

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear - there's no default constructor for `Note`. Either create one, or initialize `Note` in the initializer list with an existing constructor.

> I want that member to be empty until I use my setter method to set the right data.

You can't. Both `note` and `playback_type` exist when you create your object.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Note` doesn't have default constructor (i.e parameterless constructor), you have to initialize it in the member initialization list as:

```
PlaybackHelper::PlaybackHelper() : note(/*..args...*/) 
{                              //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^member initialization

}
```

Pass the appropriate argument(s) to `note` as required by `Note` constructor. You've to do the same, for other constructor of `PlaybackHelper` a well.